# is it safe to uninstall GDM, when using LightDM

Tags: 11.10

I'm trying to clean up my system by removing unnecessary packages. Is there any drawback when doing a `sudo apt-get purge gdm`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No drawbacks, no risks, but make sure that LightDM works for you first! :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you do a `sudo apt-get remove gdm` instead, leaving out the purge, if anything does go wrong and you cannot log into a graphical session you can always drop to a terminal and restore gdm.

After the remove if everything works properly you can then purge the config files

Comment: I'd really like to accept both answers…